# Run SQL Query With Len() In Join Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am trying to run a sql query but I am getting the error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Sample-XYZ' to data type int
```

I am not certain why the query is trying to convert to `int` as it should be `varchar`

This is sample DDL

```
Create Table Sample ( oli varchar(100), qs int )
Create Table Sample1 ( onum varchar(100), sd datetime2 )

Insert Into Sample (oli, qs) Values
('Sample-XYZ-3', 22), ('Sample-CCC-1', 11), ('Test-ABC-34', 10)

Insert Into Sample1 (onum, sd) Values
('Sample-XYZ', '2020-04-03 14:17:33.8530000'), 
('Sample-CCC', '2020-04-03 14:17:33.8530000'),
('Test-ABC', '2020-04-03 14:17:33.8530000');

Select
CAST(left(oli, len(oli) - charindex('-', reverse(oli) + '-')) As INT) As oli
,SUM(COALESCE(qs,0)) As qs
FROM Sample sl
INNER JOIN Sample1 sp
ON len(sl.oli) - charindex('-', reverse(sl.oli) + '-') = sp.onum
GROUP BY sl.oli
```

What must I change so that the query executes succesfully?

Comment: The problem is your `ON` clause: `len(sl.oli) - charindex('-', reverse(sl.oli) + '-')  = sp.onum` The left side of that expression is going to return an `int`, as both `LEN()` and `CHARINDEX` return `int` values and an `int` minus an `int` equals an `int`, but `sp.onum` is very clearly not a numerical value. I don't know what you are trying to achieve there, as the clause doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to cast to an int in the first place, maybe your real life problem is more confusing than this. But removing the cast simply works:

```
SELECT      LEFT(sl.oli, LEN(sl.oli) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(sl.oli) + '-')) AS oli
,           SUM(COALESCE(sl.qs, 0)) AS qs
FROM        Sample sl
INNER JOIN  Sample1 sp
            ON LEFT(sl.oli, LEN(sl.oli) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(sl.oli) + '-')) = sp.onum
GROUP BY    sl.oli


+------------+----+
|    oli     | qs |
+------------+----+
| Sample-CCC | 11 |
| Sample-XYZ | 22 |
| Test-ABC   | 10 |
+------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The left half of this condition is giving an int:

```
ON len(sl.oli) - charindex('-', reverse(sl.oli) + '-') = sp.onum
```

Since the LEN and CHARINDEX functions both return integer values. If that was what you were looking for (to match on any sp.onum values that are numbers stored in varchar), you could just cast that int to varchar:

```
ON cast((len(sl.oli) - charindex('-', reverse(sl.oli) + '-')) as varchar(50)) = sp.onum
```

But if sp.onum is actually a string, I'm guessing you're trying to get a substring from sl.oli, but that's not what your code is doing. You'd need to add the [SUBSTRING function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and adjust your arguments.

Comment: I thought the ``len(sl.oli) - charindex('-', reverse(sl.oli) + '-')`` would return everything to the left of the last hyphen, which would create the join on both tables.  Am I incorrect here?

Comment: You'd need LEFT(sl.oli,len(sl.oli) - charindex('-', reverse(sl.oli) + '-')) to do that. Your current code is giving "the int location of the last character of sl.oli before the last -", so you're missing the part that applies that to the actual string from sl.oli.